# assigning constant in state in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is this method of writing code here where we say

```
const {
         month,
        } = this.state;
```

in this particular  block of code ?

```
previous() {
        const {
          month,
        } = this.state;

        this.setState({
          month: month.subtract(1, 'month'),
        });
      }
```

Comment: Thats object destructuring ...?

Answer (score 2):

This is called Destructuring Assignment (ES6 Feature).

**ES6**

```
const { month } = this.state;
```

**ES5**

```
const month =  this.state.month;
```

More details you can get it from http://es6-features.org/#ObjectAndArrayMatchingDefaultValues

Answer (score 0):

It is called destructuring. You can find details [here](https://amido.com/blog/using-es6-destructuring-in-your-react-components/).

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring Assignment in es6 :

```
let obj = {key1 : "string", key2: ()=>'function'};
const {key1, key2} = obj;
console.log(key1) // returns 'string'
console.log(key2()) // returns 'function'
```